# How to create lines and text in d3.js geojson map?

Tags: angular, d3.js, geomap

In image, specific states contain lines and text to identify states.

How to create those lines and text like below image using d3.js geojsonmap in angular?

**Expected result:**
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the most straightforward way would be manually by adding and placing individual lines and text.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please go through this link, on how to ask questions : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.